# PayPal pre-approval processing without a website

Tags: paypal

I'm writing a mobile app that allows a user to send a payment to another user via the app. I'm attempting to implement this using PayPal - it looks like adaptive payments with a preapproval would be the way to go, to make the payment experience as slick as possible for the user.

Looking at how pre approvals are set up, it seems that the only way to get the resulting key is by catching it in server code for the success URL that's passed in as a parameter. The hope was to have this mobile app be stand-alone and not have a website/service.

Is there any way to direct the user to the preapproval URL in a webview and catch the key (on success) from a mobile app?

Thanks!